# Firebase : Not able to link phone number with other AuthProviders javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented emailpassword, google and facebook sign in on my web app. But in previous version phone based signin was also there which I had to remove. So I want the previous users to be linked with other options.

I am trying to link phone number to password based account.

[image]

Below code is working and the linking is working perfectly but the problem is I want the user to be signed in with password based account and not the phone number based.

[image]
Below is the error that I am getting.

> signInWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a
> valid credential.'

```
async function codeVerification(verificationId, verificationCode){

  try {
   const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode)

   const prevUser = auth.currentUser;

   // prevUser.linkWithCredential(credential);

   auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
   .then(user => {
    const secondUser = user.credential;
    auth.currentUser.delete()
    .then(() => {
      return prevUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(secondUser);
      auth.signInWithCredential(secondUser);
      //this is the step where I am getting error I guess, because I am signing in with phonenumber but how to store current credentials of user

    })
  });


 } catch (error) {

 }
}
```

I want the user to be signin with the password based account only not with the phone number. How can I implement this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you had users logging in with their phone numbers before which you no longer want to allow, however you don't want to lose the user information at the same time, so what you're trying to achieve is to make their phone number into their password?